# Get a signal when any new process starts

Tags: python, linux, process, cuda

In python, is there a way under Linux to get a signal each time a new process starts? And in particular when a process with compute context on an Nvidia GPU starts? Or do I need to use a loop that calls ps or nvidia-smi?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "CUDA process" so it is not obvious what you are trying to ask here

Comment: I meant a process running a compute context on an nvidia GPU. I have edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NVIDIA maintain an API for querying the state of the CUDA ecosystem from user code called [NVML](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/nvml-api/index.html)(NVIDIA Management Library). 
I am unaware of any Python bindings for the API, but it would not be too difficult to use it via the method of your choice (eg. [this](https://docs.python.org/3.6/extending/extending.html) or [this](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html)).  You would need to poll, it doesn't support signalling. I assume that nvidia-smi uses NVML internally.

I don't believe there is any sort of Linux user space API which would allow notification of new process creation, CUDA enabled or otherwise.